# Windows 10 dynamic mirror showing "Failed"

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I had Windows 7 running 2 x 1TB hard disks in a dynamic mirror setup. I had this for many years and it worked just fine.

I recently installed Windows 10 on a new SSD. Everything booted fine but my existing 1TB drives didn't show up in explorer.

When I looked at the hard disks in disk management they are both there, and both listed as online. The volume is showing that it has failed.

I can reactivate the disks but it does nothing. My only option when I right click on the volume is to delete it.

When I click on "reactivate disk" it brings up a popup that recommends I run chkdsk after the disks are brought online (they are already online). This is proving a bit hard because there are no drive letters assigned.

I'm sure the hard disks are healthy. I don't even really care about keeping the mirroring any more - I just want to have the data back!

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? I am in the same situation, having upgraded from Win7 to Win10, and actually, I believe I may have accidentally deleted a system/boot partition on one of the drives with a mirrored volume. I wonder if it could be related.

Comment: Not sure how technical you are, but getting the disk into a Linux OS may be more helpful. You could boot a Linux Live CD or USB and see if you can see the files and copy them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is using Testdisk ( https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk ) and recover the partitions.
I deleted it in the Windows Disk Management first (tried deleting one of them, hoping the other would stay and that I could recover from it, turns out it deleted both of them.)
Testdisk could then recover the partitions on both drives, they now appear as two separate partitions. Life is good again.