# Disk Mirror Failed After Clean Windows Reformat

Tags: windows, hard-drive, chkdsk

I don't remember the specification of my late windows 11 but my HDD disk was working perfectly fine despite not having been defrag for a couple of months.

Recently I reformatted my PC with a new windows 11 and the first thing I noticed was that there was a missing disk in my explorer. Checking out my disk manager was this:

[image: Disk Manager]

I've been trying to find a solution in forums and [Troubleshooting Disk Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc787481(v=ws.10)#BKMK_12) for weeks now but to no avail. I also tried to reinstall the disk driver from the device manager, reactivated the disks and installing *Seagate tools* running diagnostics. I

s there perhaps something wrong with the BIOS that I'd need to flash the BIOS as well? or is the disk corrupted? it'd be best if I wouldn't need to format the disk as I have 1TB of data within them that I'd like to keep. Does anyone know how to resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Oh, also not sure if it's worth mentioning but before reformatting windows there was a problem with powering down my PC whether it be sleep, shut down or restart. The PC just went into BIOS plenty of times when sleeping and a couple of times when restarting and shutdown.

Hard Disk Type:
Seagate BarraCuda 2TB 3.5" SATA 256MB 7200RPM Internal HDD - ST2000DM008

I have already ask this question over [Microsoft forums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1045274/disk-mirror-failed-after-clean-windows-reformat.html) but doesn't get any decent solutions. I'm refraining from flashing my BIOS as it's not recommended? after researching through. Having no disk label, I run *HD Tune* on the disk and get no errors as well as `chkdsk` using `mountvol` didn't seem to fix anything. Last resort, I'm also considering claiming warranty for the disks issue.

In addition, before writing this question, I also recently clean reformatted windows for the 3rd time and notice previous I had a burst mouse click issue although that was also a clean formatted windows but that went away with this one, I'm starting to think that my BIOS has an issue.

Comment: I don't think "failed" refers to the physical drive, although it could eventually be the root cause, but to the dynamic disk configuration (software/Windows RAID). I think person who closed this question doesn't really understand the issue and there's not a single mention of the need for data recovery in OP to referring to a data recovery related answer is nonsense IMO.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen yes I believe the physical disk is fine as well using the recovery tools I could see the data are recoverable.

Answer (score 0):

##### Change a dynamic disk back to a basic disk

Per Microsoft:  *Dynamic disks have been deprecated from Windows and we don't recommend using them anymore. Instead, we recommend using basic disks or using the newer Storage Spaces technology when you want to pool disks together*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk

I assume that when you installed Windows 11, you didn't first completely format the disk or remove the volumes.  Depending on the way the OS was installed (seperate volume?), simply removing the volumes will resolve the problem.

Disk utilities wouldn't care about this information and it has no bearing on the health of the drive.

Windows sees the dynamic volumes' entries but recognizes that they are in a failed state.

Comment: Yes, I didn't format any other disk except the system disk where windows are installed on separately. I did delete any volumes or partition and freshly install the OS. I see but the documentation shown is for windows server... does it also apply for normal windows? that makes it failed to recognize the disks?

Comment: Do you have 1 or 2 physical disks? Can you show us all the drive entries in disk manager and the complete width?

Comment: In total, I have 5 internal disks in my PC: 1 NVME for the system 2 SSDs basic disks and 2 HDDs which I made dynamic disks. I would like to show you however, I'm outside working atm, so I'll edit them later when I get back

Comment: Np. So you still have access to the 1 tb of data on the dynamic disks?

Comment: No, I don't there's no label for the disk nor does it appear on the explorer.

Comment: It was a mirrored array and you are trying to retrieve the 1tb of  data?

Comment: Yes they're a mirrored volume where I setup them up referring to this [video](https://youtu.be/WyJjo-YmA5w) (using the 2nd option) when they're still new and I'm trying to make them online again.

Comment: You need to look at the partition with a partition manager lthat can convert without losing data.  See [Aeomi](https://www.diskpart.com/dynamic-disk/dynamic-disk-missing-7201.html) and [testdisk](https://superuser.com/a/1336976/)

Comment: Is there no other way to return them to healthy state instead of converting them back to basic?

Comment: Unlikely but if they were mirrored the likelyhood of retrieving your data off one is high.

Comment: Hello, It's been quite a while, I've been trying out the program you suggested, however, I don't have the extra budget to spend for one-time use of `Aeomi` so instead I went with `testdisk` instead. I can't seem to find any function for converting a dynamic disk to a basic disk, so it's been quite a while waiting for it to recover by copying all the data within to an external disk where I can start over again afterwards.